# I keep getting these PHP error messages when trying to use MySqli

Tags: php, mysql

I've provided the code, so people can better help me. Okay, I'm doing a `PHP` tutorial based on YouTuber mmtut's tutorials. Using local `PHPMyAdmin`, double checked that my naming conventions are all right, and am getting these two errors:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMySQL\index.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMySQL\index.php on line 12

My PHP code:

Within the includes folder:

```
$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "phplessons";

$conn = "mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName)";

?>
```

Within the index.php file:

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($resultCheck > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['subject'];
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your $conn shouldn't be a literal

Comment: You should not have quotes around `mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);`, you are turning it into a string, not a function call

Answer (score 3):

Your connection property is a literal. You want something like this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```